# Does Izanagi really require both Senju and Uchiha DNA?

Tags: naruto

From the Chapter 510, you can see Tobi talking to Konan

[image: Izanagi]

Tobi happens to mention that *Izanagi is available only to those with the power of both Senju and Uchiha*. Is it really true? Because in the very next line he happens to mention that it is the power of the *Sage of Six Paths*.

That means either of the below 2 things are not-true.

1. We know that when Itachi explained Izanami to Sasuke, he happened to mention why the Izanami was created. It was because the Uchiha folks back then, used Izanagi for all wrong reasons. And most of those Uchiha certainly did not have the Senju DNA. So if what Tobi said was true, this has to be false.
2. If what Itachi explained about Izanagi's misuse is true and that every Uchiha who knows the jutsu Izanagi can use it, then what Tobi mentioned to Konan was wrong.

So which of the following is true? Or probably what Tobi told Konan was a plot-hole by *Kishimoto*?

Comment: My doubt is that if both Senju and Uchiha cells are mixed, then won't the Rinnegan get awakened?

Comment: This is a comment. And they shouldn't be posted as an answer. Nevertheless, since you've the doubt. I'll tell you. Just by having both the DNAs doesn't awaken the Rinnegan. It is evolved from the Sharingan. It's your Sharingan that evolves and becomes a Rinnegan. That's why Danzo did not have the Rinnegan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Summary

Izanagi is a technique available to all Uchiha members with the Sharingan, but it has various levels of effectiveness:

> The Uchiha, descended from the Sage, are able to perform Izanagi with their Sharingan ... To use Izanagi to its full potential, users must also have the genetic traits of the Senju, who are also descended from the Sage.

So, Itachi didn't lie, Obito didn't lie, and it is not a plothole. You can see how my answer clashes with the accepted answer.

#### Normal Izanagi

For normal Sharingan users, Izanagi can help you change reality for a brief moment.

#### Incomplete Izanagi (it's better)

For Sharingan users with Hashirama's DNA, it extends the lifespan of the jutsu. Since Danzo had Senju DNA in his right arm, he was able to extend Izanagi for each eye up to a minute.

> Danzō had some of Hashirama Senju's DNA transplanted into his arm, which extended the time span of each Sharingan's Izanagi to a minute. However, because Danzō is not an Uchiha, his chakra levels drop substantially every time a new Sharingan is used to activate the technique.

[image]

#### The Complete Form of Izanagi (the best)

Finally, we have the Uchiha members who can control Hashirama's DNA — Obito and Madara. Obito's Izanagi can last much longer than Danzo's (surviving Konan's signature move), and he doesn't need to use any hand seals. As for Madara, he never uses Izanagi with Senju's DNA transplanted into him, although it is shown that Senju's DNA heals his right eye in the end.

> Obito also makes use of Hashirama's DNA but, in contrast to Danzō, he claims to have gained control over Hashirama's DNA and as such, boasts the completed form of Izanagi. Showing evidence to this claim, Obito could maintain this technique's power much longer with a single eye than Danzō and could perform it with no hand seals at all.

#### Madara's Izanagi Trick

Madara had the Izanagi activated after his death, and his blind eye was healed by Hashirama's DNA.

> But Madara had planned ahead: he had scheduled an Izanagi to activate sometime after his death, changing reality to bring him back to life in exchange for his right eye's vision ... went into hiding with ... a mouthful of Hashirama's flesh that he transplanted into his wounds .. in the process restoring his right eye.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So as for your theory:

1. We know that when Itachi explained Izanami to Sasuke, he happened to mention why the Izanami was created: it was because the Uchiha folks back then used Izanagi for all the wrong reasons. And most of those Uchiha certainly did not have the Senju DNA. So if what Tobi said was true, this has to be false. **TRUE**

   > If Tobi was true, then Itachi statment (or his explanations) would be false. But unfortunately Itachi statments are true; therefore Tobi's explanation was wrong.
2. If what Itachi explained about Izanagi's misuse is true and that every Uchiha who knows the jutsu Izanagi can use it, then what Tobi mentioned to Konan was wrong. **TRUE**

   > Tobi did bluff Konan prior to her death. Tobi's explanation was wrong. He did try to exaggerate himself.
3. Whether it is a plot hole by Kishimoto.

   > I wouldn't say that it was a plot hole as Tobi always had a tendency to exaggerate himself. He does call himself Madara all the time (**before the actual Madara got reanimated**).

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Before answering, we have to consider the fact that Kishi sensei doesn't leave chances for plot holes.

The two instances where Izanagi is discussed formally are during :

1. Itachi and Sasuke's fight against Kabuto
2. the Konan vs Tobi fight

[Itachi explains to Sasuke](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/When_It_Turns_9_o%27clock) how the Izanagi and Izanami are very much related and what role they played in the Uchiha history. However, Itachi mentions that the Uchihas were able to use Izanagi. This contradicts Obito's explanation. Well, not really.

What Obito said was

[image]

Notice how he said *incomplete* form of Izanagi. In the fight between Obito and Konan, Obito was able to surprise Konan by escaping her *10 minutes of paper bomb explosion*, using Izanagi. This was considered the complete form of Izanagi (Obito's thoughts) because Obito had control of Hashirama Senju's DNA. Whereas Danzo's Izanagi was considered incomplete because of the control he lacked over Hashirama's DNA.

So there exists two types of Izanagi: the complete form and the incomplete form. To perform the complete form, you need full control of Senju DNA and of course, Sharingan. The incomplete form however, needs only the Sharingan and a good amount of chakra.

Hence, both cases are TRUE, leaving no plot holes. Seems both Itachi and Obito were right, but the entirety wasn't revealed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we all know that:

> Izanagi can be used only by those with the genetic traits of the Sage of the Six Paths. The Uchiha, descended from the Sage, are able to perform Izanagi with their Sharingan. In exchange for the brief control of reality that it allows them, the Sharingan with which Izanagi is cast becomes blind.

so by this, you have to be the descendant of the Sage Of Six Paths, but it doesn't state that you must have both Senju's and Uchiha's DNA. As you've explained the Itachi tale, those Uchihas were not Senju's, nor did they have DNA, so Obito lied (maybe he didn't know, since he possessed Senju's DNA + Sharingan, so he just thought), more likely this one than a plot hole.

Answer (score 0):

Tobi/Madara was incorrect in many of his statements. Whether a plothole/lie/etc.

There was this example of the Izanagi...
Then there was also the time where he swore to Sasuke that the 9-tails attack he himself perpetrated, was a natural disaster and wasn't perpetrated by anybody, specifically Uchiha. Although he himself is Uchiha...

But then again, so was Itachi. When he stated that Sasuke could be only the 3rd to master the Mangekyo. Implying himself and Madara. But then, there were all of those in the Izanagi story, they all had Mangekyo. Let's assume he didn't know that history at the time. There was still Madara's brother, who he told Sasuke had achieved the Mangekyo, which was then stolen by Madara for the EMS (according to that story). Then let's assume he didn't know about THAT story at the time either. Shisui GAVE HIM his Mangekyo (the only one with a 4-sided design, and likely would have been the most powerful EMS pair if they were able to be implanted into anyone. PLUS, Fugaku, who could control the 9-tails with his. Though Fugaku could be considered filler and not cannon, Shisui is DEFINITELY canon. So the whole Mangekyo, EMS, Izanagi/Izanami situation is extremely confusing if you try to sort it out based on their statements

Answer (score 0):

Uchihas can only preform an incomplete Izanagi. That's why your above quite says brief control of reality, although that really isn't too clear. But many previous episodes, that people have shown here already, prove it's not a plot hold because Obito does know that a Uchiha's Izanagi isn't complete like one who also possesses Senju's DNA.

People seem to think a big difference is Obito creating much longer alternate realities and he doesn't need hand signs. I'm not sure but I don't think Danzo using hand signs has anything to do with it being incomplete. Most likely he just needs to sign to direct his chakra to those eyes because they are on his arm, rather than a normal eye connected to ones brain.

We also don't know for sure that Obito's Izanagi is complete because it can last 10 minutes. He would not have had to continuously change reality for 10 minutes. He would just need to alter the event before he fell or use it for a second to get out of the pit. Surely not using it for 10 minutes. He would fall in the pit for 10 minutes. So he would transport body so he doesn't get hit by the bombs for his 5 minute maximum. And then 5 minutes of using Izanagi to change each result of every bomb explosion? Just doesn't sound like that's what he did

Answer (score 0):

Rinnegan only awakens in Indra reincarnation with Senju powers in Uchiha body, plus in point of death (Like Madara for old age or Sasuke vs Madara while Kabuto saved him injecting Hashi cells) It's not a plot hole, but true facts, that's why Obito didn't awakened Rinnegan while Sage path yep