# If Tobi could use the izanagi, which requires both Senju and Uchiha DNA, then why wasn’t he able to awaken the Rinnegan on his own?

Tags: naruto

It was stated by Tobi during his fight with Konan that Izanagi can only be used by those with both the DNA of Senju and Uchiha. We also know this is how the rinnegan is awakened, so why didn’t this happen?

Comment: just to clarify, the Izanagi is not needed to awaken the Rinnegan, i'm not sure where you got that info from? Also, [this post](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/does-izanagi-really-require-both-senju-and-uchiha-dna?rq=1) will explain some misunderstandings

Comment: Never said it was needed. Just said that the same requirement was meant for both. Which meant if you could do izanagi (requires Senju and Uchiha), then you have met the requirements for the rinnegan (requires Senju and Uchiha). But it seems it was because he didn’t have EMS yet. Thanks for the post though. That’s what cleared this up for me.

Answer (score 3):

Tobi was not able to awaken the [Rinnegan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Rinnegan) despite having both Uchiha and Senju DNA because he was missing a certain step in the evolution, and that is, the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan.

> (I slightly explained obito's case in one of my [previous answers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48995/would-naruto-awaken-rinnegan-if-he-take-sharingan-from-sasuke/48997#48997))

The evolution of the Sharingan involves firstly awakening the Mangekyo, then after a combination with another family members Mangekyo, it evolves to an Eternal mangekyo sharingan, after which adding Senju DNA to the mix awakens the Rinnegan.

Tobi's Sharingan never reached the EMS and so thats why even tho he had combined both Uchiha and Senju DNA, he still was not able to awaken the Rinnegan.

Comment: This should be the answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

At first, it was believed that the mixing of Senju and Uchiha DNA resulted in the Rinnegan but it was later in the series it was clarified that it's not necessarily the DNA of both that is needed but the chakra of the Sage of the Six Paths that awakens the Rinnegan.

This was done by Madara combining the chakra of the Sage's Sons Indra and Ashura who had been reincarnated into himself and Hashirama respectively.
Of course the only people who awakened the Rinnegan (aside from the Sage) were Madara and Sasuke (who got his Six Paths Chakra directly from the Sage) who were both Uchiha with the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan so it isn't known if the Sharingan or any of it's stronger forms is required for the process.

In the filler episodes that show the Sages Past, he awakened the Rinnegan immediately after unlocking the Mangekyou stage [There were no other Uchiha-Eyes to steal back then] but as it's filler it probably cannot be considered canon.

Tobi may have had some of Hashirama's Cells implanted through his prosthetic white side which likely contained some amount of Ashura's Chakra but he lacked Indra's Half of the Sages Chakra.

Additionally, it took Madara decades for his EMS and the eye which he sacrificed for Izanagi to transform into the Rinnegan so Tobi would perhaps not have had the time even if he somehow possessed Indra's Chakra.

Comment: You do have a good point with the fact that Madara didn't' awaken his Rinnegan Immediately but rather after a long time. So it could be possible that the evolution process takes longer than usual (or maybe Madaras near death state wasn't an optimum condition for the Rinnegan).

Comment: However, going with Kabuto & Orochimaru's hypothesis (which was how the Edo tenei madara was revived with Rinnegan). A combination of the strongest uchiha and senju Dna awakens the Rinnegan. I'm pretty sure that the strongest Uchiha DNA is the eternal Mangekyo Sharingan, as for the strongest of Senju I have no idea lol. It also kinda explains why zetsu was unable to replicate awakening the Rinnegan until Madara, because Madara was the first to awaken the EMS and hence the RInnegan after he combined with Hasiramas cells

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Sadly you're wrong about the Senju and Uchiha DNA being what awakens the Rinnegan.
As I stated in my post it does not matter how much of either you have but what matters is that you have the chakra of [Indra](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Indra_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) and [Asura](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Asura_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) - the sons of [the Sage of the Six Paths](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hagoromo_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) - order to reproduce the Sages Chakra.
Kabuto and Orochimaru did not know about the sons repeatedly reincarnating and thus their theory was flawed.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin This is also said on the wiki:
`The Rinnegan can typically be awakened by gaining Hagoromo's chakra either by reproducing it from combining the chakra of Hagoromo's sons, Indra and Asura,[7] or by directly receiving chakra from Hagoromo himself.`
And in the scene Kabuto talks about his and Orochimaru's Theory Madara refutes it by saying that the Rinnegan was a Power Kabuto did not create.
Madara had his Rinnegan because he had it at the time of his death and thus it was "stored" with his soul. The Edo Rinnegan disappeared upon resurrection since the eyes were removed later.

Comment: Firstly, Indra and Ashura are the ancestors of the Senju and uchiha clan, hence combining the chakra of their direct descendants (although not as potent) will still give you a bit of Hagoromo's Chakra.  Take the Izanagi for example, remember Danzo? he was able to use the izanagi for 1 minute, which is way more than a normal Sharingan can perform it. Read what the Wiki says on how the izanagi can be made to last longer, it says "recreating hagoromo's chakra by combining the genetic material of his other descendants". Even Obito was able to use Izanagi for almost 10 minutes because of that.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin The Reason Black Zetsu only managed to create the Rinnegan with Madara is either that Madara & Hashirama were the first reincarnations of the Sages' sons or if there were other reincarnations before them he was unable to manipulate them into performing the necessary acts for some reason. (For example because one or both died very early)

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin There is no indication anywhere in the series that Senju or Uchiha Chakra more impure than that of his sons could be used to make the Rinnegan.
The Presence of both Uchiha and Senju DNA does make the Izanagi last longer but the requirements of the Izanagi while similar are NOT the requirements of the Rinnegan.

If it were possible to mix the chakra of any Senju and Uchiha to get the Rinnegan were likely that someone before Madara would have awakened the Rinnegan because B-Zetsu knew the EMS secret and could have implanted the flesh and eyes of nearby corpses into an Uchiha.

Comment: It seems like your not paying attention to what I am really trying to say. I never said the requirements for the Izanagi are the same as that of awakening the Rinnegan. What i meant was in order to use the Izanagi for longer periods, one has to recreate Hagoromo's Chakra (its also stated in the Wiki) and if Danzo was able to use it for 1 minute after having both random Uchiha eyes and Hashiramas chakra then he was able to recreate the Sages chakra to a degree. This means that it is not necessary to have a reincarnation of Indra or Ashura but rather, a descendants chakra is sufficient

Comment: Now to your other comments, If you rewatch Itachi vs Sasuke, you will see where itachi stated that Madara was the first Uchiha to awaken the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan. No one before him had pulled that off before. So zetsu couldn't have been able to recreate it

Comment: Also, Madara gave his rinnegan to Nagato, hence he lost his rinnegan after his death. That is exactly why when he was resurrected with the rinnegan(when black zetsu possesed Obito and made him use the rebirth jutsu) Madara came back without any eyes at all. This thereby shows that the eyes he was using were artificially created specifically for the Edo tensei Madara. And if Kabuto was able to successfully recreate a "lesser rinnegan" then there has to be some truth to this theory. Don't you agree fam?

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin I just took a look at the Izanagi page again think the wording in the article is a bit unfortunate since from my understanding Izanagi is based on Creation of all things - which the Sage was famous for - using Yin & Yang Chakra and thus I **suspect** Izanagi is strengthened by having chakra **like** the Sages as in: a good Yin & Yang Chakra which are inherent to the Uchiha and Senju which is why having both is a great boon to Izanagi since it is strong and balanced (Tobi's two sides) - like the Sages- but does not make the Rinnegan since its not Hagoromo's chakra specifically.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin What Kabuto did was augment Madara's (Indra's) body with Hashirama's (Asura's) Chakra resulting in Hagoromo's Chakra. Of course it would increase the likelyhood of Edo Madara having the Rinnegan. This does not invalidate my theory.
This discussion is long enough already and I do not feel like writing any more about this. I admit that my view of the situation may not be completely foolproof and may have mistakes because of my small assumptions though I'm still convinced of my arguments because it is made very clear by Black Zetsu that mixing Asura and Indra is what's required.

Answer (score 0):

Technically Izanagi doesn't require both the DNA for activation as mentioned [here](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Izanagi) but to maintain it for a long time both the DNA are necessary.

According to me Obito doesn't have any direct intake of Hashirama's DNA. All he is able to do is sort of wear the Black Zetsu which doesn't lead to mixing of DNA.

Answer (score 0):

Izanagi does not require Uchiha and Senju DNA. As long as you have sharingan you can use Izanagi if you know how to activate it.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references. Specify specific anime episodes and manga chapters, if needed.